# Can this subquery be written as a join and still get the same result set/number of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

How do I write the below as a join and get the same number of rows?

```
SELECT
  s.subjectid,
  s.subjectname,
  (SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.Classes AS c
  WHERE c.SubjectID = s.SubjectID
  AND c.MondaySchedule = 1)
  AS numofclasses
FROM dbo.subjects AS s
ORDER BY numofclasses DESC
```

I am trying to write it like below but getting a different answer:

```
SELECT
  s.subjectid,
  COUNT(ClassID) AS numberofclasses
FROM dbo.subjects AS s
LEFT JOIN dbo.classes AS c
  ON s.SubjectID = c.SubjectID
WHERE c.MondaySchedule = 1
GROUP BY s.Subjectid
ORDER BY numberofclasses DESC
```

Comment: I am trying to write it like below but getting a different answer:

Comment: select s.subjectid, count(ClassID) as numberofclasses
from dbo.subjects as s
left join dbo.classes as c
on s.SubjectID = c.SubjectID
where c.MondaySchedule = 1
group by s.Subjectid
order by numberofclasses desc

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 1):

Move the `where` condition to the `on` condition.  It is converting the outer join to an inner join:

```
select s.subjectid, count(ClassID) as numberofclasses
from dbo.subjects s left join
     dbo.classes c
     on s.SubjectID = c.SubjectID and c.MondaySchedule = 1 
group by s.Subjectid
order by numberofclasses desc ;
```

This does assume that `subjects(subjectid)` is unique (or a primary key).  If not, the two might return different results.

Comment: Wow, it did help. I am in the process of gaining more expertise in SQL and hence curious- how does just moving the where condition to on condition solve this? What is the concept/theory behind it?

Comment: @NikhilaBakurupanda . . . The `where` condition filters out rows where `c.MondaySchedule = 1`.  Those are the rows specifically created by the `left join`.  The result is the same as an inner join.